# Get Fragment context in Android

Tags: android, fragment

My activity has 5 fragments. I want to reach one of my fragment's context but when I use `getActivity()` method for reach context my codes works for every fragment. How can I specialize each fragment context ? (I mean reach only that fragment context) ?

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";
private int mPage;
ListView list1;
View view;

public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
    PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
}

// Inflate the fragment layout we defined above for this fragment
// Set the associated text for the title
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
    adapterkur();
    return view;
}

private void adapterkur() {
    Insan[] insan_data = new Insan[]
            {
                    new Insan(R.mipmap.apoprof, "Apo"),
                    new Insan(R.mipmap.baranprof, "Showers"),
                    new Insan(R.mipmap.kursatprof, "Snow"),
                    new Insan(R.mipmap.ozerprof , "Ben Delay Remix"),
                    new Insan(R.mipmap.taylanprof , "Sis Atma Och"),
                    new Insan(R.mipmap.aliprof , "BigFoot"),
                    new Insan(R.mipmap.hasanprof , "Marlboro Light"),
                    new Insan(R.mipmap.bengisuprof , "Operation"),
                    new Insan(R.mipmap.beyzaprof, "Bana yok mu"),
                    new Insan(R.mipmap.seloprof , "mega")
            };

    InsanAdapter adapter = new InsanAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.listview_item, insan_data);
    list1 = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    View header = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header, null);
    list1.addHeaderView(header);
    list1.setAdapter(adapter);
}
  }

 public class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements PagerSlidingTabStrip.IconTabProvider {
final int PAGE_COUNT = 5;
private int tabIcons[] = {R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher,R.mipmap.ic_launcher
        ,R.mipmap.ic_launcher};

public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return PageFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
}

@Override
public int getPageIconResId(int position) {
    return tabIcons[position];
}
 }
```

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you mean. I don't think I've ever encountered this problem before, and I use `Fragment`s regularly. Do you have several fragments attached to your `Activity` simultaneously?

Comment: sorry for my english , yes , i use fragmentpageradapter (tabs - viewpager), i have 5 fragment in one activity. When i set listview for first fragment, it applied all of them (because for context i use getActivity method). How can i handle it ??

Comment: Fragments simply don't have their own Context, they all use the Activity Context for the Activity they reside in.  It sounds like you will need to use a different approach with whatever you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Are the five fragments you're inflating all the same class?

Comment: Question is : **Why?** Why would you need specific context for each fragment? I'm not sure you understand what context does?

Comment: No i have 5 class like PageFragment , PageFragment1 ... which all of them extends fragment.

Comment: I use tab system with fragment ( associate with fragmentpageradapter). I want to create listview for first tab , but it created in all tabs. Because in my fragment class i use getactivity for context.

Comment: The problem doesn't lie in your use of `getActivity()`, the problem exists in your adapter. I've written up an answer that will hopefully resolve your issue.

Comment: There we go, that's your actual problem. @PPartisan got you covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at your adapter class, `SampleFragmentPagerAdapter`, you can see that you are returning a new `PageFragment` five times:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return PageFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
}
```

If you take a look at the Documentation for [FragmentPagerAdapter `getItem()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html#getItem(int)), it states:

> Return the Fragment associated with a specified position.

Thus, you are creating five lists.

If you instead would like to create separate fragments for each page, you can use a `switch` statement:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return PageFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            break;
        case 1:
            return PageFragment1.newInstance(position + 1);
            break;
        case 2:
            return PageFragment2.newInstance(position + 1);
            break;
        //etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much PPartisan

Comment: @Bad0 No problem. Please accept/upvote my answer if it resolved your issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if I got what you want, you want to get access to each fragment, to be able to modify its content and etc. Right ?

First of all, in your `Activity` *(which one contains the fragments pager..)*, you have to instatiate the pages, to be able to access them, like this:

```
FirstFragment mFirstFragment;
SecondFragment mSecondFragment;
.
.
.
```

So inside your `onCreate()` method of your `Activity`, do this:

```
mFirstFragment = (FirstFragment) adapter.instantiateItem(pager,0);
mSecondFragment = (SecondFragment) adapter.instantiateItem(pager, 1);
```

Note that the `pager` is the `ViewPager` and the `adapter` is your `FragmentPagerAdapter`

Why is it useful ?

It is because now you can do things like change view's inside each fragment **separately**, like:

```
mSecondFragment.mButton.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
```

or

```
mFirstFragment.mTextView1.setText("hello, its my second fragment's textview");
```

*Assuming that you have a `Button mButton` inside the first fragment and a `TextView mTextView1` inside the second fragment, just for example.*